# Paperclip plugin on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I tried to use paperclip plugin on rails 3-beta 3. I installed this plugin successfully, but when I use the following script to generate:

rails generate paperclip xxx xxx

it said generator not found. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also working through the same problem and we're pretty much at the same point.  Which version of the plugin did you install?  The main Thoughtbot version or the Jason King one?  I also noticed that the "rails3" branch doesn't seem to exist any more, so tried the dev-v3.0 branch instead.

Comment: Hi Eric, I used the main thoughtbot version. Have you solved the problem with dev-v3.0?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried including the Paperclip module inside your model?

```
class MyModel
  include Paperclip

  has_attached_file :picture
end
```

It's kind of a hack at the moment but it worked for me.